# SVG border gets blurry on drag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

While dragging an SVG rect the top border changes its width depending on where the rect is dragged and positioned on the screen. For example, sometimes it looks wide and blurry:

[image]

And sometimes it looks normal, well defined:

[image]

Just look at the top and left borders in each image and you'll notice the difference. Additionally, the bottom border is wider than the top border, regardless of the rect location.

The rect is defined as follows within a DIV:

```
<div>
    <svg>
        <rect width="110" height="20" 
              style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:0.5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

This behavior is identical in Chrome and IE. Is there a way to fix this? I drag with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-draggable-droppable) library.

Comment: How are you dragging it? Also, are you dragging the rect inside the SVG, or are you dragging the `<div>` that contains everything?

Comment: I'm dragging it with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-draggable-droppable) angular library. The SVG is inside the DIV that is dragged (I updated the question). Also note that the bottom border is always wider than the top border, that's also a problem.

Comment: Better question now, I'd add that library to the question as well, as a note. Regarding the problem, did you try to set the `shape-rendering` to `crispEdges`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: `crispEdges` solved the problem of having the bottom border wider than the top border, but I still have the problem of the borders getting blurry depending on the position of the `div/rect` on the screen

Comment: @Gerardo, I changed the screen resolution in Windows from 150% to 125% and the problem persists (at a different definition, since the rectangles are smaller, it's less noticeable). I also found out that if I drag HTML DIVs I have the same problem, so it's not an SVG specific issue.